# Безопасное подключение к БД

Tags: c#, безопасность, база-данных, sql

Каким образом организовать безопасное подключение к базе в десктопном приложении? Я рассматривал несколько вариантов: явное хранение строки подключения в приложении, запрос к php скрипту на сервере, организация связи клиент-сервер (запросы к бд происходят на сервере). Например, при явном хранении строки можно легко получить доступ к базе тем кому не надо.

Возможно вы предложите более лучшие варианты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю в вашем случае вас спасет клиент/серверная архитектура. То биш клиент ничего не знает про саму базу, со всеми вопросами он обращается к серверу (сервисам), естественно предварительно авторизовавшись на нем. Почитайте про WCF.